# Inserting New Records to a table from other tables

Tags: sql

I have two tables where TABLE 1 is the main table. How do I insert all records to TABLE 1 from TABLE 2 and TABLE 3 that are not existing in TABLE 1?

TABLE 1:

```
+-----------------------------+
| REC_NUM | F_NAMES | L_NAMES | 
+-----------------------------+
|    1    |  JOHN   |  SMITH  |
+-----------------------------+
|    2    |  JAMES  |  BROWN  |
+-----------------------------+
|    3    |  BRYAN  |  KENNY  | <= Not Existing in Table 2 and 3
+-----------------------------+
```

TABLE 2:

```
+-----------------------------+
| REC_NUM | F_NAMES | L_NAMES | 
+-----------------------------+
|    1    |  JOHN   |  SMITH  |
+-----------------------------+
|    2    |  MARY   |  JANE   | <= Not Existing in TABLE 1
+-----------------------------+
|    3    |  WILL   |  BROWN  | <= Not Existing in TABLE 1
+-----------------------------+
|    4    |  JAMES  |  BROWN  |
+-----------------------------+
```

TABLE 3:

```
+-----------------------------+
| REC_NUM | F_NAMES | L_NAMES | 
+-----------------------------+
|    1    |  JOHN   |  SMITH  |
+-----------------------------+
|    2    |  STAN   |  CRAIG  | <= Not Existing in TABLE 1
+-----------------------------+
|    3    |  JAMES  |  BROWN  | 
+-----------------------------+
```

Result will be...
TABLE 1:

```
+-----------------------------+
| REC_NUM | F_NAMES | L_NAMES | 
+-----------------------------+
|    1    |  JOHN   |  SMITH  |
+-----------------------------+
|    2    |  JAMES  |  BROWN  |
+-----------------------------+
|    3    |  BRYAN  |  KENNY  |
+-----------------------------+
|    5    |  MARY   |  JANE   | <= New Record from TABLE 2
+-----------------------------+
|    6    |  WILL   |  BROWN  | <= New Record from TABLE 2
+-----------------------------+
|    7    |  STAN   |  CRAIG  | <= New Record from TABLE 3
+-----------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
insert into table_1 (f_names, l_names)
select f_names, l_names
from table_2 t2
where not exists (select 1 from table_1 t1 where t1.f_names = t2.f_names and t1.l_names = t2.l_names)

union

select f_names, l_names
from table_3 t3
where not exists (select 1 from table_1 t1 where t1.f_names = t3.f_names and t1.l_names = t3.l_names);
```

This sql will work fine if REC_NUM is auto incremented.

Answer (score 0):

Below query in MS SQL Server would work.

```
;WITH CTE_Table2AndTable3 AS
(
SELECT REC_NUM, F_Names, L_Names FROM Table2
UNION 
SELECT REC_NUM, F_Names, L_Names FROM Table3
)
MERGE Table1 AS target
USING CTE_Table2AndTable3 AS source
ON target.REC_NUM = source.REC_NUM AND target.F_Names = source.F_Names AND target.L_Names = source.L_Names
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (REC_NUM, F_Names, L_Names)
VALUES (source.REC_NUM, source.F_Names, source.L_Names);
```